# Power over coax standard

Tags: video, standard, coax

We are specifying a system to use power over coaxial cable, that will transmit SDI video.

Is there any standard (IEEE or otherwise) for implementing it?

Comment: Mind that users might be tempted to use whatever coax they have that meets the impedance spec - and that the DC handling capability of the various options will vary brutally. Forcing a few amps over RG-179 could fail in interesting ways...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any standard for it, but one of my clients has a proprietary system that does power + SDI over coax. For safety, they apply a low voltage to the cable first, and only if the equipment at the other end does a proper handshake, they then apply full power. That way, if an end user has connected an ordinary SDI camera or display, nothing will get blown out.